# how to use javascript onkeyup for multiple ids at sametime

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html textbox for users to enter numbers. To sum those numbers, I am passing the values to JavaScript variable and after addition displaying the result to html div section

```
<div class="input-left"><span><input  class="textbox" id="left" name="count" type="text" size="5"  value="" /></span></div>

<div class="input-right"><span><input  class="textbox" id="right" name="count" type="text" size="5"  value="" /></span></div>

<div id="result"> </div>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('left').onkeyup = function() {
    var a = parseFloat(this.value);

}

document.getElementById('right').onkeyup = function() {
    var b = a + parseFloat(this.value);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = b || 0 ;
}
```

But  I have an issue with JavaScript. It not displaying the result. How to add both functions in same onkeyup function.

[**FIDDLE SETUP**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gYV8Z/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    var right = document.getElementById('right');
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    left.onkeyup = calc;
    right.onkeyup = calc;

    function calc() {
        var a = parseFloat(left.value) || 0;
        var b = parseFloat(right.value) || 0;
        result.innerHTML = a + b ;
    }

}
```

JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gYV8Z/3/

**Update:** To hide the result in case the sum equals zero , change the last line like this:

```
        result.innerHTML = ( a + b ) || "";
```

JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gYV8Z/4/

Comment: +1, though I wouldn't suggest `window.onload` because that happens so late. Probably best just to put the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Cherniv : This working, will I able to hide the result which shows as  0 after I remove values from both textbox

Comment: @user1128648 have a look at my update , is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('left').onkeyup = function() {
var a = parseFloat(this.value);

}

document.getElementById('right').onkeyup = function() {
var b = a + parseFloat(this.value);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = b || 0 ;
}
```

it your code, var a is local variable. make it global variable.

but i would use this code.

```
function add(){
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById('left').value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById('right').value);
}

document.getElementById('left').onkeyup = function() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add();

}

document.getElementById('right').onkeyup = function() {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add();
}
```

Comment: *"make it global variable"* Creating globals is almost never the right solution (and certainly not here).

Comment: i understand this question just right onKeyup events can calculate.